# Transforming a path made out of line segments from $A$ to $B$ so that it goes from $C$ to $D$ and keeps its shape

Tags: linear-transformations

My linear algebra skills are seriously rusty, so hopefully someone can help me a bit. So, I do have a 3d-path made out of line segments that goes from $A$ to $B$ and want to transform it so it goes from $C$ to $D$ but looks otherwise like the original.

I would think there must be a linear transform that would do the trick. But to me it seems like two target points are too little to calculate a transform that could potentially have translation, rotation and scaling components.

Am I wrong? How would I go about finding the solution if there is one?

Comment: So does it have rotation and/or scaling or not? In the beginning you say that it doesn't, and in the end you say that it could "potentially" have.

Comment: I don't know whether it has them because the points C and D could be anything.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand! So basically we assume that yes, there is scaling and rotation. And we know two points in the beginning, and two points in the end. Got it.

Comment: So you have a set of points, for each of which you have to make an affine transformation. I think it would be easiest to make this in steps: 1) Calculate the scaling factor $\frac{|DC|}{|BA|}$; position vector for point $A$, $\vec{v}_A$, and the rotation angle between $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{CD}$; 2) Move the point cloud so that $A$ would be in the origin; in other words subtract $\vec{v}_A$ from the points; 3) scale the components of the point cloud by the scaling factor calculated earlier; 4) turn the points by the rotation angle; 5) move the point cloud back to the correct position.

Comment: Thanks, Matti P, I will have to try that one.

Comment: The five-step approach provided by **Matti P** works according to my test!

Comment: Yay :) As you see, it's always a good idea to break a difficult task into smaller pieces! I wish you a good weekend.